# Assigning the value of a formula to a variable

Tags: vba, variables, variable-assignment, formula

I am learning coding in vba and I recently encountered a serious problem: I cannot assign the value of a formula to a varialbe without putting the variable to a cell first.

My point is that I need those value to do some other task, but I don't want to to put those formula to a cell (if I do, it will takes a lot more coding).

I did try this:

```
Dim Total As Integer
Total = FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(R1C1,R3C2)"
```

But I realize that this only return bolean value which obviously not my attention

So my main question here is: How can I assign the value of a formula (in string or integer type) to a variable

In addition, as using FormulaR1C1 requires a refernce cell, do I need to select a cell before assigning to make it work

Comment: Where is your formula coming from? Can you give an example?

Comment: you could also show more of your code in your question for better understanding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one option which could be interesting for you. You could call `SUM` worksheet function calling it from VBA through `WorksheetFunction` object. How it works?

Based on your example you could get sum of your `R1C1` & `R3C2` (A1 & B3) this way:

```
Dim Total As Integer
Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1,B3"))
```

As you can see it is required to use `Range object` referenced to cell which you need to sum up. You can't use `R1C1` references here. But I think it's not a problem.

One more tip. It's allowed to call it also this way:

```
Dim Total As Integer
Total = Application.Sum(Range("A1,B3"))
```

The biggest difference of two above examples is the way of error handling. Working with `WorksheetFunction`- any error will stop your procedure, working with `Application`-error will be thrown as a text without procedure brake.

The other tip- if you write `WorksheetFunction.` (dot at the end is essential) you'll get list of approx 200 function available for you to use. If you start with `Application.` there will not be a list of function but just methods and properties of `Application Object`.

Finally, see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff847328%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for more information regarding using `WorksheetFunction`.

**EDIT** One more thing, this could be obvious but make it clear. To sum continuous range from A1 to B3 you need just small change:

```
Dim Total As Integer
Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A1:B3"))
```